# Rótulos para box plot no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Tenho esse gráfico criado pela função `geom_boxplot`. Gostaria de rotular cada boxplot, corretamente. O que estou fazendo errado? Estou usando o fator errado?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EQpCdv9VVCCO3ERJrstYSX6dnu8tLulC/view?usp=sharing

```
df1<- read.table("TBZ_2.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

df.m1 <- melt(dados1, id.var = "ID")
  
df.m2 <- filter(df.m1, variable == "BRANCO")

ggplot(data = df.m2, aes(x=variable, y=value, label=ID)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=ID)) +
  labs(x = "Equipamentos", y = "Resultados (NTU)") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 12) +
  facet_wrap(~`variable`,scales = "free") +
  geom_text(data = df.m2, aes(group=ID), size = 3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maioria dos gráficos feitos com o `ggplot2` segue um esquema do tipo

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x = VariavelX, y = VariavelY))
```

No caso do teu problema, a variável a ser colocada no eixo X é `ID`, enquanto `value` será colocada no eixo y. A partir disso, fica trivial fazer o gráfico.

```r
df1<- read.table("~/TBZ_2.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

require(reshape2)
#> Loading required package: reshape2
require(ggplot2)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
require(dplyr)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df.m1 <- melt(df1, id.var = "ID")

df.m2 <- filter(df.m1, variable == "BRANCO")

ggplot(data = df.m2, aes(x = ID, y=value)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=ID)) +
    labs(x = "Equipamentos", y = "Resultados (NTU)") +
    theme_grey(base_size = 12) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

Note que os rótulos foram colocados automaticamente, tanto para o eixo x quanto para a legenda, sem necessidade de comandos extras.

Além disso, acredito que a função `facet_wrap` talvez não seja uma boa opção nesse caso. Ela serve para dividir o gráfico em painéis, o que pode prejudicar a visualização dos boxplots deste problema.

```r
ggplot(data = df.m2, aes(x = ID, y=value)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=ID)) +
    labs(x = "Equipamentos", y = "Resultados (NTU)") +
    theme_grey(base_size = 12) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
    facet_wrap(~ ID, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro é necessário calcular as posições `y` dos rótulos. Para colocar os rótulos em cima das caixas, vou usar a estatística `max` e, em `geom_text`, o argumento `vjust`.

```
df.labs <- aggregate(value ~ ID + variable, df.m2, FUN = max)
```

Este data.frame vai ser a base para o texto dos rótulos.
Uma alteração importante no gráfico é ter `x = ID`. A variável `variable` serve para definir as facetas, não as caixas.

```
ggplot(data = df.m2, aes(x = ID, y = value, fill = ID)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(data = df.labs, 
            mapping = aes(x = ID, y = value, label = ID), 
            size = 3, vjust = -1) +
  labs(x = "Equipamentos", y = "Resultados (NTU)") +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 12) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para ter todos os paineis, calculam-se os valores `max` tal como acima mas em vez de `geom_text` vou usar `geom_text_repel` do pacote `ggrepel`, uma vez que os rótulos estavam sobrepostos.

```
library(ggrepel)

df.labs.1 <- aggregate(value ~ ID + variable, df.m1, FUN = max)

ggplot(data = df.m1, aes(x = ID, y = value, fill = ID)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text_repel(data = df.labs.1, aes(x = ID, y = value, label = ID), 
            size = 3, vjust = -1, direction = "y") +
  labs(x = "Equipamentos", y = "Resultados (NTU)") +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 12) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Será que entendi errado o que o AP queria dizer com rótulos? Me parece redundante ter a informação EPXX em dois locais diferentes, como fiz, mas em três locais (eixo x, legenda e acima de cada caixa) é bem esquisito.

Comment: @MarcusNunes Pois é mas é isso que está no gráfico da pergunta. Às tantas quer outra informação (valores das medianas, por exemplo) mas na pergunta estão os `EP`'s bem alinhados na vertical.

Comment: É, faz sentido.

Comment: @MarcusNunes Não, não creio que faça. Lá vão 15 pontos mas é assim:).

Comment: Eu quis dizer que o teu raciocínio faz sentido, não o gráfico pedido : )

Comment: @MarcusNunes muito obrigado pela ajuda! Ajudou demais =)